# Should I use "was" or "would" in the following sentence?

Tags: sentence-construction, modal-verbs, conditional-constructions

> I had to find a place to keep my dead dog. I thought of the house, but then
>   decided it *was/would be* too unsanitary."

What's the correct option? And why? (Or maybe both are correct but just mean different things?)

Answer (score 2):

> I had to find a place to keep my dead dog. I thought of the house, but then decided it **was** too unsanitary."

Here, you say that the house itself was too unsanitary. It was already unsanitary when you thought of it, even without the dead dog inside.

Or, per Araucaria's comment, it more likely means

> I thought: "*To keep my dead dog in the house is too insanitary.*"

---

Variation 2

> I had to find a place to keep my dead dog. I thought of the house, but then decided it **would be** too unsanitary.

Here, you say that the house **would become** too unsanitary if you decide to keep your deceased dog there.

Comment: I'm not sure that your first interpretation is necessarily correct. I think what I thought was *It is too insanitary to keep my dead dog in the house* which just means *To keep my dead dog in the house is too insanitary*.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, @Araucaria! I felt like I was missing something!

Answer (score 1):

You should use "would". Because at the time you thought of the house, you decided if you were to keep the dog in the house, the house would become unsanitary